# Use jQuery to look for specific file extensions and add attribute

Tags: jquery

I'm wondering if someone can help. I'm trying to use jQuery to look for specific file extensions in an href and if it finds it add an attribute "data-lightbox". This is what I have thus far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var valid_extensions = /(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif\.png|)$/i;   
    $(".banner ul li.dfwp-item a").each(function() {
        filename = $(this).attr( "href" );
    });
    $(".banner ul li.dfwp-item a").each(function() {
        if(valid_extensions.test(filename))
        { 
            $(this).attr( "data-lightbox", "BannerLightbox" );
            alert('Woo hoo');
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Invalid File');
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using two `.each()`?

Comment: Join the two `each` together, and move the last `|` between gif and png

Comment: Because I'm new to this and have no idea what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your corrected code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var valid_extensions = /(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.png)$/i;   
    $(".banner ul li.dfwp-item a").each(function() {
        filename = $(this).attr("href");
        if(valid_extensions.test(filename))
        { 
            $(this).data("lightbox", "BannerLightbox");
            alert('Woo hoo');
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Invalid File');
        }
    });
});
```

You need to drop the second `.each()` and move the pipe (`|`) in your pattern. You can also use `.data()` instead of `.attr()`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a pipe between .gif and .png, but you have an extra pipe after that which would match anything.